# Mouse move event outside of form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events

I am creating a C# WinForm application and I want to detect mouse movement when the mouse is outside the form.

I already tried to create new thread that continually calculates the mouse coordinates, it work well as a job, but it uses `while(true)`. It's really inefficient for CPU.

Comment: `it work well as a job but it uses 'while(true)' so it's really inefficient for CPU` it seems you are asking for a review and or other suggestions. If that's the case, head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as that place would be best.

Comment: thank you to review my question, I am looking for the right way to do, because using 'while(true)' is no solution.

Comment: you're welcome. The question itself is broad and or could generate many opinionated answer's here of which both are off topic.

Comment: I was thinking there maybe some way to create an event function that will be trigged when mouse move outside of form or something similar, but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: [Control.MouseLeave Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Edit (missunderstanding from first time) :

Working example -->

```
private void MainForm_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(0, 0);
        MoveCursor(300, 300);
        MoveCursor(400, 400);

    }
    private void MoveCursor(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(X,Y);
    }
```

Comment: thank for your answer @Kuba Do, but what I really want is function like mouse move that work outside the form.

Comment: Sorry missunderstanding from my side

Comment: @Kuda Do, am really thankful for your try, but let me ask my question better, as we have 'MouseMove' event function which gonna be trigged every time the mouse move, I need that, but the problem is 'MouseMove' is not working outside the form, I need to detect mouse is moving or not when it's outside           I reached to solution that says use 'HookManager', but I still working on it, not shure how it work and what it requires. thank u again.